# Django rest framework foreign key constraint fails creating model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following in a Django Rest Framework setup:

**models.py:**

```
class Sku(BaseModel):
    sku_code = models.CharField(max_length=18, primary_key=True)
    supplier_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    soh = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    reserved = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    broken = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    unallocated = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    reorder = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Reservation(BaseModel):
    sku = models.ForeignKey(Sku, db_column='sku_code')
    order_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class SkuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sku
        fields = (
            'sku_code',
            'supplier_id',
            'soh',
            'reserved',
            'broken',
            'unallocated',
            'reorder',
            'created_at',
            'modified_at',
        )


class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sku = SkuSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = (
            'id',
            'order_id',
            'sku',
            'created_at',
            'modified_at'
        )
```

**views.py:**

```
class ReservationList(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                      generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReservationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sku = get_object_or_404(Sku, sku_code=request.data['sku_code'])
        request.data['sku'] = sku
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now when I post to the url linked to ReservationList.post view above I get the error: `IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'sku_code' cannot be null")`.

It seems to be bypassing the serializers validation and failing on the database layer. For some reason it doesn't accept the SKU being passed in.

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried to follow the example at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships but this seems to break down with the `CreateModelMixin`. I can't tell if there is something wrong with how my models or serializers are set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set the sku field to `read only`, that's why the serializer is ignoring it when you post.

From the [relevant documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be
>   included in the input during create or update operations. Any
>   'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
>   input will be ignored.

Comment: Arg, so annoying that I didn't spot this. I had made it `read_only` as it should not be updated, but needs to be set at creation time. Do you know if there is a way to handle this type of scenario, or would I need to cater for it specifically?

Comment: Overwrite get_serializer() in the view and there test the method - if it's create then remove the field from the read-only fields (_meta class). Or, perhaps cleaner, overwrite get_serializer_class and return a different serializer when creating objects then when updating them.

Comment: @nicja yeah just do it manually. Remove the `read_only` arg and add `required=False` then make sure the serializer doesn't receive the sku during updates.